# Does the trace of the tensor of inertia have any physical significance?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia, trace

The [tensor of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor) is given by
$$I_{ij} = \sum_k m_k \left( r_k^2 \delta_{ij} - x_{k,i} x_{k,j} \right).$$

In my experience, the trace of a physically important tensor tends to also be important. The trace of the tensor of inertia - the sum of the three principal moments of inertia - equals
$$2 \sum_k m_k r_k^2.$$
Does this value have any physical significance? I don't recall having come across it before.

Comment: Good question..

Comment: Note that the trace is invariant to rotations, so examining the MMOI tensor along the principal directions would be sufficient for the general case.

Comment: Also note that for a planar body the perpendicular axis theorem states that $I_3 = I_1 + I_2$, which means that ${\rm tr}({\bf I}) = I_1 + I_2 + I_3 = 2 I_3$

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, Cartesian tensors are not very intuitive. It's clearer to use spherical tensors. Given a symmetric tensor, $T_{ij}$, the relevant spherical tensors are:

$$ T_0^0 = \frac 1 3 T_{ii} $$

and with $S_{ij} = T_{ij} - \frac 1 3 T_{kk}$ being the symmetric traceless natural rank-2 tensor:

$$ T_2^{\pm 2} = \frac 1 2 \big(S_{xx}-S_{yy} \pm 2iS_{xy}\big)$$
$$ T_2^{\pm 1} = \frac 1 2 \big(S_{zx}\pm iS_{yz}\big)$$
$$ T_2^0 = \sqrt{\frac 3 2}S_{zz} $$

The $T_l^m$ are related to $r^2$-weighted projections onto the spherical harmonics $Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)$.

With the right choice of axes, the $T_2^{\pm 1} = 0$ leaving 3 parameters:

1. $T_2^0$ describes if the object is prolate/oblate relative to the $z$-axis
2. $T_2^{+2} + T_2^{-2}$ describes that quadruple deviation from cylindrical symmetry along the $z$-axis
3. $T_0^0$ roughly describes how spherically symmetric the object is (versus a quadruple moment...higher order moments will not be captured)

Comment: Okay, so what's the answer to my question?

Comment: see point (3). It's how much of $mr^2$ is spherically symmetric, when compared with the other $T_2^m + T_2^{-m}$....shoud probably use real spherical harmonics, but I didn't have time to look them up.